# Por que este método me retorna 2?

Tags: python, recursão, árvore-binária

Estou com um código para analisar e não estou conseguindo ao certo compreender por que este método da minha Árvore Binária me retorna 2.

Código:

```
class No:
def __init__(self, dado):
    self.esq = None
    self.dir = None
    self.dado = dado 

class Arvore:
def __init__(self):
    self.raiz = None
def pegarRaiz(self):
    return self.raiz

def inserir(self, val):
    if self.raiz == None:
        self.raiz = No(val)
    else:
        self._inserir(val, self.raiz)

def _inserir(self, val, node):
    if val < node.dado:
        if(node.esq != None):
            self._inserir(val, node.esq)
            node.esq.pai = node
        else:
            node.esq = No(val)
    else:
        if node.dir != None:
            self._inserir(val, node.dir)
            node.dir.pai = node
        else:
            node.dir = No(val)

def resp(self):
    if(self.raiz != None):
        return self._resp(self.raiz)
def _resp(self,node):
    aux_esq = 0
    aux_dir = 0
    if node.esq != None:
        aux_esq = self._resp(node.esq)
    if node.dir != None:
        aux_dir = self._resp(node.dir)
    if (node.esq != None) or (node.dir != None):
        return 1 + aux_esq + aux_dir
    else:
        return 0
 T = Arvore()
 T.inserir(15)
 T.inserir(9)
 T.inserir(5)
 T.inserir(12)
 T.inserir(20)
 T.resp()
```

Após o programa rodar ele me retorna 2, por quê?

Comment: Os `def`s deveriam estar identados um nível a mais que os `class`, né?

Comment: Considerando a observação do @VictorStafusa , eu creio que `resp` deveria retornar a quantidade de nós da árvore, mas isso não funciona nas folhas. Pelo que estou vendo, como para folhas ele retorna 0, ele deve estar retornando a quantidade de elementos internos, que no caso são apenas 15 e 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos arrumar a identação e visualizar a árvore formada (acrescentando-se métodos `__str__`):

```
class No:
    def __init__(self, dado):
        self.esq = None
        self.dir = None
        self.dado = dado

    def __str__(self):
        s = '(' + str(self.dado) + ','
        if self.esq != None:
            s += str(self.esq) + ','
        else:
            s += 'X,'
        if self.dir != None:
            s += str(self.dir) + ')'
        else:
            s += 'X)'
        return s

class Arvore:
    def __init__(self):
        self.raiz = None
    def pegarRaiz(self):
        return self.raiz

    def inserir(self, val):
        if self.raiz == None:
            self.raiz = No(val)
        else:
            self._inserir(val, self.raiz)

    def _inserir(self, val, node):
        if val < node.dado:
            if node.esq != None:
                self._inserir(val, node.esq)
                node.esq.pai = node
            else:
                node.esq = No(val)
        else:
            if node.dir != None:
                self._inserir(val, node.dir)
                node.dir.pai = node
            else:
                node.dir = No(val)

    def resp(self):
        if self.raiz != None:
            return self._resp(self.raiz)

    def _resp(self, node):
        aux_esq = 0
        aux_dir = 0
        if node.esq != None:
            aux_esq = self._resp(node.esq)
        if node.dir != None:
            aux_dir = self._resp(node.dir)
        if (node.esq != None) or (node.dir != None):
            return 1 + aux_esq + aux_dir
        else:
            return 0

    def __str__(self):
        if self.raiz != None:
            return str(self.raiz)
        else:
            return 'X'

T = Arvore()
T.inserir(15)
T.inserir(9)
T.inserir(5)
T.inserir(12)
T.inserir(20)
print(T.resp())
print(T)
```

Eis a saída:

```
2
(15,(9,(5,X,X),(12,X,X)),(20,X,X))
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/J81Nms)

Olhando para a árvore temos isso:

```
    15
   /  \
  9    20
 / \
5   12
```

Olhando-se então para o `resp`, ele faz isso:

- Nas folhas (5, 12 e 20), `aux_esq` e `aux_dir` são zero, nenhum dos `if`s entra e chega-se ao `return 0`
- No nó intermediário (9), os três `if`s entram. Entretanto, os dois primeiros não mudam os valores de `aux_esq` e `aux_dir` que continuarão zero. O terceiro avaliará o `1 + aux_esq + aux_dir` como `1 + 0 + 0` e retornará 1.
- No nó raiz (15), os três `if`s entram. No primeiro, teremos 1 atribuído a `aux_esq`. No segundo teremos 0 atribuído a `aux_dir`. No terceiro o `1 + aux_esq + aux_dir` será avaliado como `1 + 1 + 0` e retornará 2.

A minha conclusão é que esse método está contando o número de nós internos (não-folhas) da árvore. No caso da árvore dada, os nós internos são o 9 e o 15. Isso faz sentido, pois o `if (node.esq != None) or (node.dir != None):` só vai entrar em nós não-folhas (internos), o que significa que para nós folhas, 0 será sempre retornado. Como para os nós internos, temos o `return 1 + aux_esq + aux_dir`, que vai retornar o número de nós internos de cada subárvore filha mais um para considerar a si próprio.

Comment: Obrigado Vitor, novamente! Sabia que ele contava os nós 'pais' mas não entendia como chegava ao resultado, grande ajuda!